# How to create a Sumifs-like function in SQL with the criteria being the value in each row?

Tags: sql, sqlite, select

I am familiar with Excel VBA, but just got started with SQL using SQLite Studio. I have a table like the following one:

```
Customer_ID    Qty_Sold
Retail001      10    
Retail001      20  
Retail002      30   
Wholesale001   100  
Wholesale001   100   
Wholesale001   100
Wholesale002   200 
Wholesale003   500 
Wholesale003   600
```

and I wish to classify the customer into 3 categories: Retail, Wholesale Small, and Wholesale Large, with Qty Sold greater than 1,000 being Large Wholesale Customer. So the desired result is like this:

```
Customer_ID    Qty_Sold    Classification
Retail001      10          Retail
Retail001      20          Retail
Retail002      30          Retail
Wholesale001   100         Wholesale Small
Wholesale001   100         Wholesale Small
Wholesale001   100         Wholesale Small
Wholesale002   200         Wholesale Small
Wholesale003   500         Wholesale Large
Wholesale003   600         Wholesale Large
```

I have problem with using a 'sumifs-like' function to figure out how many each customer have bought. So in the context of Excel VBA, I can use For Next loop and If Then statements to do this, so I can write for example:

```
WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Range("B2:B9"), Range("A" & i), Range("A2:A9")) > 1000
```

with i being the counter in the loop.
However, in SQL I find it is hard to realize because the Customer ID is not a hard coded string, it is dynamic based on different rows. Here are some code I have tried with:

```
Select customer_id, qty_sold,
Case
    When customer_id Like 'Wholesale&' And (...) > 1000 Then 'Wholesale Large'
    When customer_id Like 'Wholesale&' And (...) <= 1000 Then 'Wholesale Small'    
    Else 'Retail'
End As Classification
From Base_Table
;
```

For the (...) part is where I don't know how to write. I think it might be something like:

```
Sum(Case When customer_id then qty_sold end) > 1000
```

but I don't know how to refer to the value in each row.

Comment: Edit your question and clarify how you want the rows to be classified. Why the id of the customer is important?

Comment: The ID of customers serves two purposes, first it is used to distinguish between Retail and Wholesale customers; second, in order to tell Large or Small wholesale customer, amount from each customer must be summed according to ID, for example, Wholesale customer 003 had two transactions, both have to be marked as 'Wholesale Large' although each single transaction did not exceed 1,000. So in Excel formula Sumifs, the Customer ID is the criteria, and the first column is criteria range. Sorry for being unclear, I will try my best to clarify. Thank you!

Comment: Ok, but it is a strange way to use a column like id. Anyway I think that the answer from Mureinik solves the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The challenge here is the need to display two types of information - row information and aggregate information for each row based on the total sum of sales.

One approach for this is to join a query on the table with an aggregate query, and then apply the categorizing logic:

```
SELECT b.customer_id, 
       qty_sold,
       CASE
            WHEN b.customer_id LIKE 'Retail%' THEN 'Retail'
            WHEN b.customer_id LIKE 'Wholesale%' AND total > 1000 THEN 'Wholesale Large'
            WHEN b.customer_id LIKE 'Wholesale%' AND total <= 1000 THEN 'Wholesale Small'
            ELSE 'I don''t know'
       END AS classification
FROM   base_table b
JOIN   (SELECT   customer_id, SUM(qty_sold) AS total
        FROM     base_table
        GROUP BY customer_id) a ON b.customer_id = a.customer_id
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I feel it is very smart to use join table here to get around this problem! So here it doesn't matter whether it's Inner join or Left Join because they have the same key right? And your syntax is "b Join a On (key)" so why type of join is it? Thank you!

Comment: @Passer-by a left/right join differs from an inner join only if you want the keys on one side that aren't on the other. Here, we want only the keys that match in both, so I'm using an inner join. Stating `join` without inner/outer/left/right is implicitly an inner join.

Comment: Thank you, so I see that 'Inner' is optional. But I was wondering here two table will have the same key values, it's just Table b will have a IDs, and Table a will only have each appear once, so could I say that Table b to Left Join Table a is also correct? (result will have the same length as the original table/Table b, and Table a's key values to match each of those of Table b)

Comment: @Passer-by you'll get the same result with both types of joins, yes. Personally, I would use a left join, as it suggests that one table might have keys the other hasn't, which isn't the case here.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a modern version of sqlite (3.25 or newer), you can use window functions to make it pretty easy:

```
select customer_id, qty_sold,
       case when customer_id like 'retail%' then 'Retail'
            when sum(qty_sold) over (partition by customer_id) > 1000 then 'Wholesale Large'
            else 'Wholesale Small' end as classification
from base_table
order by customer_id, qty_sold;
```

Comment: Thank you, I am using SQLiteStudio (3.2.1), it should be the latest as I downloaded from the website recently. Is partition by a function? But my SQLite did not highlight it in bold and gives error in red wavy line.

Comment: @Passer-by It's part of the window definition. See https://www.sqlite.org/windowfunctions.html or look up a window function tutorial.